# Multiple use of .post in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

Good day!

I am trying to use jquery .post(). My problem is I want to get data from 2 different Action (java-struts2). Instead of getting the data of test2, it results to resending the page twice... so the data in my JSP also doubles.

My code is as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $.post("test", function(data) {
      $("#tester").html(data);
    });

    $.post("test2", function(data) {
      $("#tester2").html(data);
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tester"></div>
<div id="tester2"></div>
```

How can i do the retrieving the data from 2 different actions(java) without the need of sending the data twice?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send the JSON response from the server, group the data together something like this:

```
{
  "tester": [foo, bar],
  "tester2": "hello world"
}
```

In your `$.post` callback, you will now have access to both piece of data in your `data` var.

```
console.log(data.tester)   //=> [foo, bar]
console.log(data.tester2)  //=> hello world
```